# Handling Custom Security in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I know there is a ton of information out there about MVC and security already. However, there is so much that I'm having trouble figuring out what the best practice would be for my situation with an intranet MVC 4 app.

We have a custom built WebForms app that manages a SQL Server db to handle all of our internal app security. Currently we have a BasePage that we inherit all of our pages from which checks on load whether the user is in the security group(s) specified in the Web.config. It also defines a UserSession class with UserID, FirstName, LastName, and SecurityGroupID. There are a couple of functions to populate this into the Session variable if it is not there, etc. This allows us to pull the user's name for the home page and things such as that.

So, the question is... What would be the cleanest way to access this Security System in MVC, check if the user has access each time he hits a page (redirecting to access denied if not), and store the session information for use on the Layout page. Please include organizationally where any classes or models should go, as that is part of what is confusing me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you rebuilding the WebForms app from the ground up in MVC?

Comment: I'm just looking to create a new app in MVC for internal use. I don't need to change any of the existing systems. However, I'm not sure how to handle security in MVC, or the best way to save info to the Session. I gave some detail about the way the WebForms apps are handling security just to give more context about what I was trying to accomplish in MVC

Comment: So are you wanting to authenticate and authorize people with this new app using the existing database?

Comment: The equivalent would be to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that you apply to your controller (or base controller so applies to all controllers and all actions).  My preferred option is to throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` and let your global error handler handle it (then all errors are handled in same place).

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Should I store the user's information in the Session or in a ViewModel? I need to show their Name in the nav bar.

Comment: Have you tried with attributes?